# Camera Unity2d в скриптах

Tags: c#, unity3d, камера

Создаю игру на Unity и нужно получить координаты мыши.Для этого я использовал `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);`
Unity выдает ошибку.Ранее я с таким сталкивался.Чтобы это решить я перед "Camera" писал еще одно имя класса, на подобии "имя класса.Camera.main....".Кто знает пожалуйста подскажите название этого класса.
Ошибка:

> error CS1061: 'Transform' does not contain a definition for 'postion' and no accessible extension method 'postion' accepting a first argument of type 'Transform' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Не подключено пространство имен? Какое-нибудь "using UnityEngine;"?

Comment: Да, на подобии того, но не могу вспомнить какое именно.Как не гуглил, не нашёл инфы

Comment: ну так пиши ошибку в своем вопросе)